# jQuery: there is a way to apply colour (tint) to an image?

Tags: jquery, tint

there is a way to colour (apply tint)  an image using jQ or some plugs?
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in [Dynamically changing image colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241863/dynamically-changing-image-colours/8242063#8242063)

take a look at **Pixastic** (coloradjust)

https://github.com/jseidelin/pixastic

http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/coloradjust/

or **PaintbrushJS** (colour tint)

https://github.com/mezzoblue/PaintbrushJS

http://mezzoblue.github.com/PaintbrushJS/demo/

Answer (score 16):

Simplest way I can think of is overlaying a semitransparent div over the image.

A little example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
<img id="myimg" src="img.jpg" />
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay
    {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(200, 100, 100, 0.5);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    }
```

**JS (with JQuery)**

```
overlay = $("#overlay");
img = $("#myimg");
overlay.width(img.css("width"));
overlay.height(img.css("height"));
overlay.css("top", img.offset().top + "px");
overlay.css("left", img.offset().left + "px");
```

Comment: Nice idea - a simpler, faster solution to using GD/ImageMagick with PHP, especially if the OP can't use PHP!

Comment: Excelent idea! Worked great and saved me a lot of time using js colorizing libraries.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/yewTq/ .  Unfortch, this technique applies the tint to the area surrounding the image.

Comment: Warning: this will also brighten any black in the image to not-black.

Answer (score 4):

nico's answer is great if you're after a simple tinge of a colour - however, if you're talking about desaturating an image and *then* applying a tint (so that the image is only in green for example) then you can have a look at image manipulation with `<canvas>`

After some googling, I found this library for canvas that focuses on photo manipulation operations: https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you're using PHP, but it's not possible with JavaScript/jQuery. With PHP, you can use the GD image library to tint the image before it's sent to the client. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951960/how-can-i-tint-transparent-png-files-in-php) should help :-)

Also, [this forum thread](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=600376) talks about ImageMagick to tint the image as well.

I'm very sorry if you aren't/can't use PHP, however JavaScript can't do what you want.

James

Comment: This isn't a link-only answer, but only barely, so other reviewers will probably opt to delete it.  Include some content from those links if you want to save it.