# tint images without imagemagick

Tags: php, image, tint

I have an upload form for images that once uploaded are then displayed automatically and randomly on a website. I would like to apply a colour tint to the images before they are saved, at the very least one green but preferably various colour tints which are saved in relevant folders /green/ /red/ /blue/ etc. so I can make skins for the site.

My hosting package doesn't allow me to install imagemagick so I'm looking for a way to achieve these results in html css and php preferably, as that's where my limited knowledge lies, but if that's not possible I will consider other options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: there is a way to apply colour (tint) to an image ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416007/jquery-there-is-a-way-to-apply-colour-tint-to-an-image)

Comment: The duplicate above answers your question with CSS, with or w/o jquery.

Comment: i'm having problems with the css due to the fact that the images are used at a random size between x/x pixels both vertically and horizontally, the background colour ends up not matching the area of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is gdlib enabled?
or you use aviary or one of their apis http://developers.aviary.com/filter-list
http://developers.aviary.com/

Update: as Aviary is no more offering this service as before but here are some more good solutions:

take a look at **Pixastic** (coloradjust)

https://github.com/jseidelin/pixastic

http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/coloradjust/

or **PaintbrushJS** (colour tint)

https://github.com/mezzoblue/PaintbrushJS

http://mezzoblue.github.com/PaintbrushJS/demo/

Comment: no gdlib but aviary may be just what i'm looking for! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP on your hosting package is compiled with the GD library you could use that instead. [imagefilter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php)