# How to access object.style.filter for firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm using `object.style.filter='Gray'`, `object.style.filter='fliph'`, `object.style.filter='flipv'`, `object.style.filter='invert'` this is working in IE, but in firefox its not working. Can u help  for this.

Answer (score 2):

`.style.filter` in Firefox exposes the `filter` CSS property that SVG defines.  Valid values for this property do not include `'Gray'`.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#FilterProperty and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/applying_svg_effects_to_html_content#Example.3a.c2.a0Filtering

Answer (score 0):

Filters are IE specific.  CSS will work to set the color in both IE and FF:

```
object.style.backgroundColor = 'gray'
```

If your goal is to tint the entire div, your best bet is to create a new div which covers the first, and is partially transparent.

Comment: @Zake It's not working in firefox, but also it apply as a background. Inside the div any image is there, that thing also i want to change the color, like as shade.

Comment: Ah, then the best way to do it is to use a partially opaque div in front of the first, here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416007/jquery-there-is-a-way-to-apply-colour-tint-to-an-image/4416015#4416015