# Image height always returned as 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416007/jquery-there-is-a-way-to-apply-colour-tint-to-an-image) SO answer on how to tint an image, but when i do it, `$("#myselector").height();` keeps been returned as 0. What am I doing wrong? Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  overlay = $("#overlay");
img = $("#myimg");
overlay.width($("#myimg").width());
alert($("#myimg").height());
overlay.height("100");
overlay.css("top", img.offset().top + "px");
overlay.css("left", img.offset().left + "px");

});


</script>

<body id="home">

<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
<img id="myimg" src="building.png" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: on your source , he use overlay.height(img.css("height"));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use image' `load` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  overlay = $("#overlay");
  img = $("#myimg");
  img.load( function(){
    overlay.width($("#myimg").width());
    alert($("#myimg").height());
    overlay.height("100");
    overlay.css("top", img.offset().top + "px");
    overlay.css("left", img.offset().left + "px");
  });
});
```

Comment: You are a beautiful person. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

My best guess is that the image isn't loaded yet.

Your script runs `onready`. If you change it to `onload` you'll probably get a better result.

Change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

to

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

More: [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

on:

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

Comment: In an answer like this explaining what effect the change has is important. Why do you think `$(window).load` is superior to `$(document).ready` in this case?