# Get Hex Value From Farbtastic and convert to RGB for use in imagefilter in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've got a working jquery code snippet that gets the hex value of my color picker farbtastic just fine. Problem I am having is taking that and applying it as a tint with  paintbrushjs. The Hex just does not transfer over to the id of the image and does not update the data-tint-pb-colour option. So I am possibly looking at a php option but would like input first on a possible fix as I've worked on this 3 days now and unable to get it to work.

## JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').hide();
    $('#picker').farbtastic('#color');
  });
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var picker = $.farbtastic('#picker');
        picker.linkTo(function onColorChange(color) {
        $('filter-tint').attr('data-pb-tint-colour',color)
        console.log(color, "hello world!");
        });
     });
```

## HTML

```
<form action="" style="width: 400px;">
  <div class="form-item"><label for="color">Color:</label><input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" /></div><div id="picker"></div>
</form>
 <img id="filter-tint" class="filter-tint" src="http://preview.88kcikfcuw4mfgvi8ckrxvjrndu6jemi01t025rhda6skyb9.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Layer2.png" data-pb-tint-opacity="0" data-pb-tint-colour="#ffffff"/>
```

I've basically hit a wall. Not sure how to make this work.
 [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sg02Lctb/8/)

Comment: You don't need to duplicate your `$(document.ready(){...})`. Also, you forgot the hash symbol (#) in `$('#filter-tint').attr('data-pb-tint-colour',color)`. Now, you will see your attribute changes. However, the paintbrush still does not seem to work. Why? I'm not sure. Perhaps because `Firefox / Chrome only work when files exist on a web server.` You can find this message at their [github repo](https://github.com/mezzoblue/PaintbrushJS)

Comment: @BishopBarber, I have tested this on a codeanywhere devbox and I am still not having any luck getting it to tint with paintbrushjs. Do you have any other suggestions for tinting a image with Jquery?

Comment: @BishopBarber also to note when I put a hex value in data-pb-tint-colour manually it tints it. But updating it via the color picker does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind not using PaintbrushJS, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4416015/2835243) which proposes to overlay a semitransparent div over your image. So basically, you set the div's dimensions and position equal to the image's dimensions and position. Then you set its background-color. Since you want the color to be transparent, you want to set a `rgba` value to the background-color. However, farbtastic returns a hex color, so you have to convert it to a `rgba` value.

First add the div:

```html
<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
```

The class overlay would have the following css at load:

```css
.overlay
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then add the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#picker').farbtastic('#color');
    var $picker = $.farbtastic('#picker');    
    SetTintColor($("#color").val()); // Set tint at load too
    $picker.linkTo(function(hexColor) {
        SetTintColor(hexColor);
    });
});

function SetTintColor(hexColor) {
    var $filterImage = $('#filter-tint');
    var $overlay = $("#overlay");
    // Set the div's dimensions and position equal to the image's dimensions and position
    $overlay.css({
        "height": $filterImage.height(),
        "width": $filterImage.width(),
        "top": $filterImage.offset().top + "px",
        "left": $filterImage.offset().left + "px"
    });
    // The farbtastic plugin returns a hex color, but we want to set a rgba as the div's background-color,
    // so it can be transparent.
    var rgb = hexToRgb(hexColor);
    var opacity = 0.5; // This can be changed for a dynamic value
    // Concatenate the rgb's values + opacity to obtain a string representing the rgba
    var rgbaColor = "rgba(" + rgb.r + ", " + rgb.g + ", " + rgb.b + ", " + opacity + ")";
    $overlay.css("background-color", rgbaColor);

    // Change the color input's background-color
    var $colorInput = $("#color");
    $colorInput.val(hexColor);
    $colorInput.css("background-color", hexColor);
}

// Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624139/2835243
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}
```

So if you used PaintbrushJS only for the color tint, I suggest you simply do the above, because it's lighter, and because PaintbrushJS seems to have some problems.

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sg02Lctb/10/)

Comment: This will work perfect, my only concern is addressing the alphas so it doesn't tint over them. Other then that this will work great.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well right now it applies it as a over lay and covers the whole image, my PNG's have alpha backgrounds and I want to color only the image if possible not the background. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, it makes sense, but I'm not really sure that's possible. Even with PaintbrushJS, it tints your whole image. You can't really tint only the non-background part of your image. At least, not that I know how. Good luck though!