# How to animate image over other image in Css or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say First image is black & white.
Second image is colored.
After some timeout B/W image should  change to colored image..with animation
just like loading progress bars? how can I do this using Css or JavaScript ?

**[Added for clarity from a comment by the OP, below]**

> OP: is it possible with some slow linear kind of animation ?? like filling
>   water in glass..color filling in b/w image ?

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: there is a way to apply colour (tint) to an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416007/jquery-there-is-a-way-to-apply-colour-tint-to-an-image)

Comment: Use only one image and apply jQuery filtering function for it.

Comment: The OP has explained more clearly in a comment below the effect they wish to achieve: _is it possible with some slow linear kind of animation ?? like filling water in glass..color filling in b/w image ?_

Answer (score 1):

first place two images above each other using `position: absolute;`. With background images you can do it like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image1"></div>
  <div class="image2" id="image_resize"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height:200px;
}

.image1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/cf6/bird-1394216.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/4f3/apple-1322812.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

To animate the second image, the easiest way is to use jquerys animate. With pure javascript you could do something like this:

```
var percent = 0; // this will count from 0 to 100, defining the with in percent

/* with setinterval you can call a function periodically, in this example every 50 milliseconds */
var myInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
    /* find the image that should get resized by id */
    var img = document.getElementById('image_resize');

    /* set the with of the image */
    img.style.width = percent+"%";

    /* increment by 1 percent */
    percent ++;

    if(percent > 100) {
      /* when 100% is reached, stop the interval */
      clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}, 50);
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c51u6r8t/

Answer (score 1):

You can put the black-white image on top of the colored one at full opacity and simply fade out the black-white image when you want.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("container").className = "revealed";
}, 500);
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

#container.revealed .overlay {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2003/10/soho_image_28_october_2003/10098404-2-eng-GB/SOHO_image_28_October_2003_node_full_image_2.jpg">
  <img class="overlay" src="http://dawn.jpl.nasa.gov/multimedia/images/dawn-image-070911.jpg">
</div>
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv2xazn7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

## Second attempt

I understand better what you are trying to achieve now. This can be achieved with an animation on an `::after` pseudo-element.

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
position: relative;
width: 190px;
height: 190px;
background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/190/190');
}

div::after {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 190px;
height: 190px;
background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/190/190');
opacity: 0;
filter: grayscale(100%);
animation: waterfill 5s linear;
}

@keyframes waterfill {
0% {height: 190px; opacity: 1;}
20% {height: 190px; opacity: 1;}
100% {height: 0; opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

## First attempt:

You can use a CSS `@keyframes` animation like this:

```css
img {
width: 190px;
height: 190px;
filter: grayscale(0%);
animation: colorImage 5s linear;
}


@keyframes colorImage {
0% {filter: grayscale(100%);}
80% {filter: grayscale(100%);}
100% {filter: grayscale(0%);}
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/190/190" />
```

The animation takes 5 seconds in total.

For the first 4 seconds, the image is black and white.

During the last second, the image transitions to full color.

Comment: is it possible with some slow linear kind of animation ?? like filling water in glass..color filling in b/w image ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var picCount=0; // global
var picArray= ["Header1.png","Header1.jpg"] 
// Replace your original image names here
// gets next picture in array
function nextPic()
{ // check if adding 1 exceeds number of pics in array
picCount=(picCount+1<picArray.length)? picCount+1 : 0;
// build the img to write to page using the new pic reference
var build='<img border="0" src="'+picArray[picCount]+'" width="200" height="200">';
document.getElementById("imgHolder").innerHTML=build;
// repeat this after a puse of 2000ms (2sec).
setTimeout('nextPic()',2000)
}
</script>
```

Add this to your html page

```
<body onload="setTimeout('nextPic()',2000)">
<div id="imgHolder">
<img border="0" src="Header1.jpg" width="300" height="300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I assumed correctly, the first image is desaturated version of the second image so only one image is needed here: the colored one. To turn it into a bw image simply use grayscale filter:

```
img.desaturate {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

and add this class to your image:

```
<img id="myimage" src="image.jpg" class="desaturate">
```

if you want an "animation" you can forget the classes and dynamically add the style via jQuery:

```
$("#myimage").css("style","filter: grayscale("+(bytesLoadeed/bytesTotal*100)+"%);");
```